# JavaScript program, what's wrong?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, interpreter

Okay, I don't know where to look.  Actually, my interpreter isn't giving me anything back.  I'm not getting an alert or anything.

```
var string, output = "";
var counter = number(prompt("Where to start?");
while(; ; counter++){
  if(counter < 0){
    alert("Error.");
    break;
    }
  else if(counter => 0 >= 10){
    string += string;
    output += string + "\n";
    }
  else{
    alert("Too much.")
    break
    }
  }
alert(output);
```

Comment: Which interpreter are you using?
I see a number of what look like syntax errors to my eye (line 2, second last character should be a close parenthesis, for example.)

Comment: Please look at your JavaScript console. That code has syntax errors.

Comment: James: http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter2.html The interpreter is floating at the bottom.  It says "console", and it's green.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a number of syntax errors (as mentioned by others), and is also a little unusually-written.

- A `while` loop just takes one argument, it looks like you intended to use a `for` loop
- The variable `string` isn't needed
- `Number` will return `NaN` if the argument passed to it cannot be evaluated as a number. The code should check for this as well
- Your validation code is inside the loop. It would make more sense for this to be outside of the loop
- `output` will end up with a trailing newline. This probably isn't desirable. To avoid this you can build up `output` as an array of values, and then `join` them with newlines at the end

How about changing your code to this?

```
var counter = Number(prompt("Where to start?", "0"));
if (isNaN(counter)) {
    alert("You needed to enter a number");
}
else if (counter < 0) {
    alert("Error.");
}
else if (counter > 10) {
    alert("Too much.");
}
else {
    var output = [];
    for ( ; counter <= 10; counter++) {
        output.push(counter);
    }
    alert(output.join("\n"));
}
```

## Edit

You mentioned that you've not yet learned about JavaScript arrays, so here's an alternative code snippet for the `else` block that is closer to your original approach, of building up the string step-by-step.

```
    var output = "";
    for ( ; counter <= 10; counter++) {
        output +=  counter + "\n";
    }
    alert(output);
```

Comment: Oh, hey.  You're right about the for loop thing.  Why isn't string necessary, though?  I'm trying to get a single-alert output.  So, I add to string, and then I add string to output, with each loop.  This makes 'output' like the memory of what string has been.  I also don't know how to use arrays, yet.  That's chapter 4, and I'm on chapter 2.  And I agree with you very much that it makes more sense to put the validation code outside of the loop.  I was trying to come up with a way to do that, here.  Thank you for showing me.

Comment: Regarding the `string` variable - I don't really understand what you were trying to achieve with it. But...it's not needed.

Comment: Cool beans and very nice kudos.  Also, I was thinking....  Well, I thought I only put in the error messages because I don't know how to do arrays....  I feel like your info about handling the validation outside of the loop might be a hint otherwise.  I guess I'll wait in suspense and see as I go on.  I'll probably have to learn more about how to return values, first.  Thanks, Rich.  Excellent answering.

Comment: I'm trying to make another pyramid out of pound signs.

Comment: A pyramid out of pound signs? Good luck... :)

Answer (score 1):

1) To type cast to a number, you need to used a capitol N like the class "Number"
2) Take out the "; ;" for your while loop.
3) Semicolons are needed where lines close (good practice).

```
var string, output = "";
var counter = Number(prompt("Where to start?"));
while(counter++){
  if(counter < 0){
    alert("Error.");
    break;
    }
  else if(counter >= 0 >= 10){
    string += string;
    output += string + "\n";
    }
  else{
    alert("Too much.");
    break;
    }
  }
alert(output);
```

***gl***

Comment: Thanks for showing me how to do it with a while loop. :)  The whole point of the exercise is to give 'break' options, and I only have a limited knowledge of JavaScript.  So, this is really useful for me in its clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you meant

```
else if(counter => 0 && counter <= 10) {
```

since you have no condition that will get you to your `else` statement.